# cURL and special characters in URL

Tags: php, curl, special-characters

I am using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link)` for fetching an external site, but there are special characters `(&, ?, ;)` in some urls and curl not work.

i used `urldecode` but still no luck, also replaced special characters with encoded ones (for example, `%26` instead of `&`), but source site only returns a 404 page.

Comment: Could you please give an example URL that is not working?

Comment: sure:
example.com/Default.aspx?tabid=1298&articleType=ArticleView&articleId=1531987

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-escape.php

> // Create a curl handle $ch = curl_init();
>
> // Escape a string used as a GET parameter $location =
>   curl_escape($ch, 'Hofbräuhaus / München'); // Result:
>   Hofbr%C3%A4uhaus%20%2F%20M%C3%BCnchen
>
> // Compose an URL with the escaped string $url =
>   "http://example.com/add_location.php?location={$location}"; // Result:
>   http://example.com/add_location.php?location=Hofbr%C3%A4uhaus%20%2F%20M%C3%BCnchen
>
> // Send HTTP request and close the handle curl_setopt($ch,
>   CURLOPT_URL, $url); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>   curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);

Comment: my PHP IDE (php storm 2.1) specified `curl_escape` as "undefined function" and seems need update, anyway i'll test it on newer IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

curl_escape function is only available since PHP 5.5.

An other solution is to use the function **encode_url** written here : 
http://publicmind.in/blog/url-encoding/
It work perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

urlencode($val) works for me.
Eg: urlencode($hello#Test);
Without urlencode, values after # not passing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).